# Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling PUT

Tags: php, youtube, fatal-error, youtube-data-api

I have written a script to upload multiple videos to YouTube with their API.

the issue is that when I run script it uploads the first video fine, but in second iteration it does not properly upload the video and throws an exception:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
 message 'Error calling PUT
 https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=status%2Csnippet&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2Uov0hJdmXu0UKN65WejqwsCvdhkXuIxgftiNPfNQYRv2MLwWaqSDHBlq5rUmn7xLwAl7ZXdbK8YcFprx_6uao8of119Fw:
 (400) Failed to parse Content-Range header.' in
 /var/www/html/YoutubeApi/Google/Http/REST.php:80 Stack trace:
 #0 /var/www/html/YoutubeApi/Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php(185): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request))
 #1 /var/www/html/YoutubeApi/upload_video.php(79): Google_Http_MediaFileUpload->nextChunk('E(?03?F????N???...')
 #2 /var/www/html/YoutubeApi/upload_video.php(272): UploadVideo->upload_video('Ireland Video W...', 'Welcome to Tour...',
 '/var/www/html/Y...', Array)
 #3 /var/www/html/YoutubeApi/upload_video.php(28): UploadVideo->run()
 #4 /var/www/html/YoutubeApi/upload_video.php(308): UploadVideo->__construct()
 #5 {main}   thrown in /var/www/html/YoutubeApi/Google/Http/REST.php on line 80
```

Here is my script:

```
private function run() {
        $dir = "";
        $videos = $arr = $this->get_active_videos();
        $directory = __DIR__ . "/temp/";
        if (!file_exists($directory)) {
            $dir = mkdir(__DIR__ . "/temp", 0777);
        }

        $this->youtube_client->setAccessToken($this->get_access_token(1));
        if ($this->youtube_client->getAccessToken()) {
            foreach ($videos as $video) {
                $this->set_youtube_video_obj();
                //$channels = explode(",", $video['channel']);
                if (!strlen($video['category']) && !strlen($video['channel'])) {
                    continue;
                }
                file_put_contents("temp/video", file_get_contents($video['media_link']));
                sleep(5);
                $tags = $this->get_video_tags($video['location'], $video['event'], $video['country'], $video['video_cat']);
                $status = $this->upload_video($video['title'], $video['description'], $directory . "/video", $tags);
                if ($status['status']['uploadStatus'] == 'uploaded') {
                    if (strlen($video['category'])) {
                        $categories = explode(",", $video['category']);
                        // $video_files = $this->get_files();
                        foreach ($categories as $category) {
                            $playlists = $this->get_playlists(1);
                            //foreach ($playlists as $playlist) {
                            $cat_name = $this->get_category_name($category);
                            $this->add_video_to_playlist($status, $video['title'], $video['description'], $cat_name);
                            sleep(3);
                        }
                    } else if (strlen($video['channel'])) {
                        $tags = $this->get_video_tags($video['location'], $video['event'], $video['country'], $video['video_cat']);
                        $status = $this->upload_video($video['title'], $video['description'], $directory . "/video", $tags);
                        $channels = explode(",", $video['channel']);
                        //$video_files = $this->get_files();
                        //foreach ($video_files as $video_file) {
                        foreach ($channels as $channel) {
                            if ($status['status']['uploadStatus'] == 'uploaded') {
                                $channel_name = $this->get_channel_name($channel);
                                $category_name = $this->get_playlist_from_channel($channel_name);
                                $this->add_video_to_playlist($status, $video['title'], $video['description'], $category_name);
                            }
                        }
                        //}
                    }
                }

                $this->unset_youtube_video_obj();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

i've tried a lot of stuff but to no avail, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error and i found out that the video folder is empty 
so i think your issue is related to that you fail to set the video path correctly